# Flutter carousel slider image over image partially

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, overflow

i wanted to create a carousel slider with an image over an image. I have achieved to overlay a second image over the first with a stack, but also with positioned widget, but the problem is the overflow is not visible but i want to see it. As you can see on the image below the rounded circle overflows but the overflow is not visible.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9H4o.png)

```
class _HelpPageState extends State<HelpPage> {
 final List<Color> colorList = [
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.deepPurple,
  Colors.yellow,
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(children: [
    ListView(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
                //height: 270,
                autoPlay: true,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                autoPlayCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut),
            items: colorList
                .map((color) => Container(
                      height: 230,
                      width: 500,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
                          ),
                          color: color
                          ),
                      child: Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        overflow: Overflow.visible,
                        children: [
                          new Positioned(
                            bottom: -20,
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                                  maxHeight: 50.0, maxWidth: 50.0),
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color(0xFFdedede),
                                      offset: Offset(2, 2)),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => print("ha"),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Image.asset("icons/360.png",
                                      scale: 0.5),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          )
        ])
  ])),
);

/*return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Help Page',
  theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: const Text('Help'),
    ),
    // ignore: unnecessary_new
    body: Container(
      height: 250,
      width: 500,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightGreen,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
            blurRadius: 15,
            offset: const Offset(0, 5),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
        ),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("images/cityliner2.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          new Positioned(
            bottom: -30,
            child: Container(
              constraints:
                  new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50.0, maxWidth: 50.0),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(color: Color(0xFFdedede), offset: Offset(2, 2)),
                ],
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print("ha"),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Image.asset("icons/360.png", scale: 0.5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   
    drawer: MainDrawer(),
  ),
);*/
```

}
}

The code which is commented will result in the right behaviour but without carousel. As soon i try it with a listview following a carouselslider i get the overflow issue as above. I also tried adding "overflow: overflow.visible" but as it is depreciated there is no effect visible.

Anyone out there who can help me please.

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZwj.png)

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately so far not

Answer (score 0):

use clipbehaviour instead

```
clipBehaviour=Clip.none
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not work.